# Why do baseball players wear belts?

Tags: baseball

Baseball players wear pants with a belt.
But I really don't think it is the most appropriate or comfortable attire for playing baseball.

Is there any particular reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe they're required per MLB, but they're not explicitly mentioned in the rules, so I can't prove it.  [MLB Rules](https://img.mlbstatic.com/mlb-images/image/upload/mlb/atcjzj9j7wrgvsm8wnjq.pdf) do mention in 3.03 various things, including that "No player whose uniform does not conform to that of his team-mates shall be permitted to participate in a game."  However, they don't call out the belt specifically.  I've seen a fair amount of speculation that players are required to wear them to avoid the shirt falling out of the pants, like [here](https://baseballtrainingworld.com/a-quick-guide-to-the-mlb-dress-code/), but it seems like speculation at best from a content aggregator, so not particularly reliable.

Uni-watch does relate a [humorous story involving belts](https://uni-watch.com/2008/07/30/now-boy-dont-make-me-take-off-my-belt/) that makes it pretty clear a belt is required or at least needed, though:

> There was a slight delay as Washburn disappeared into the clubhouse to put on spikes and a jersey. He eventually re-emerged into the dugout while still tucking in his shirttails fore and aft. Just one problem: He’d forgotten to put on a belt. So Riggleman, displaying the kind of keen managerial acumen that only a man with a season-opening 14-game losing streak on his résumé can possess, took off his own belt and handed it to Washburn, who then held the belt while doing a bit more tucking, zipping up his pants, and trotting to first base, where he finally put on the belt.

I suspect the answer is mostly that baseball players wear baggy clothes (as opposed to every other major sport where more athletic, tight fitting clothes are worn) and thus belts are useful; and to a lesser extent that baseball uniforms more so than other sports are still somewhat similar to the early days of baseball, where not wearing a belt would have been odd.

Comment: There's already some variation in uniform wear (does the player wear a shirt under the jersey, and if so, is it long-sleeved; does the player wear ankle-length pants or knee-breeches, etc). I would think the choice to wear a belt would likewise be a matter of choice.

Comment: MLB Rules are ... weird.  Some of them have flexibility, some don't.  Like I said, there's nothing in the rules I see that clearly says "you must wear a belt", but clearly people think that is required...

Comment: Related: cricket is a sport in many ways similar to baseball in terms of the clothing required. Cricketers do not wear belts, but [did in the old days](https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2015/aug/29/wg-grace-first-modern-sportsman-cricket) before elasticated waistbands were used.